# Cannot convert T to interval (my own custom type)

Tags: c#

Here is my c# code, I want to use "DisplayList" to check if the type T is my custom type custom, and then use my DisplayInterval function to print it.

But there is an error that cannot convert T to intervals in the visual studio. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

Hope someone can give me an answer.

```
public class Interval
{
    public int start;
    public int end;
    public Interval() { start = 0; end = 0; }
    public Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; }
} 

public static void DisplayInterval(Interval inter)
{
    Console.Write(" [{0},{1}]",inter.start,inter.end);
}

public static void DisplayList<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    foreach (T element in list)
    {
        if (element.GetType() == typeof(Interval))
           DisplayInterval(element);

        else
            Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this, just override `ToString` for that type to define how it should be displayed.  Or, at the very least, don't make the method generic, because it's not actually generic.  Make it accept a `List<Interval>`, because that's what you're actually supporting.

Comment: Defining `ToString` looks arguably: the object should not be aware of how it should be printed to a console, unless it is its main responsibility.

Comment: I didn't say you can't.  I said you shouldn't.  It doesn't scale.  What happens when you create a new object an hour from now, and again next week, and 100 more times over the next few months.

Comment: Defining `ToString` does not scale as well: if you need to print the `Interval` instances differently depending on some context - you cannot define `ToString` twice.

Comment: @zerkms You can create new objects that format themselves differently if you need to, or simply not proport to have a generic solution in the first place, if the formatting is very narrow in applicable; I mentioned both options after all.

Comment: @Servy the whole "format themselves" idea smells. It's not the object's responsibility to know how it is to be represented in the console output.

Comment: @zerkms You prefer having an object that knows how to format every single object in existence?  And I didn't say that every object needs to be responsible for representing itself in console output, rather, if the object *does* need to be responsible for knowing how it should be represented (and it seems as if this one does) then it should override `ToString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add casting:

```
DisplayInterval((Interval)element);
```

Sometimes it is also good to override `ToString` method of your custom class:

```
public class Interval
{
    public int start; // consider to use properties: public int Start {get;}
    public int end;
    public Interval(): this (0,0) { } // you can call second constructor here
    public Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"[{start},{end}]";
    }
}
```

With your definition of `ToString` you can simply iterate elements without checking their types:

```
public static void DisplayList<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    foreach (T element in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

BTW For your original solution - you don't need to check type of each element in list. Thus they all have same type. You can check only type of generic parameter. Or even better - create separate method for displaying `IList<Interval>`.

Comment: nice way "to check if the type T is my custom type"

Comment: @Igor sorry, didn't get you

Comment: I meant that `(Interval)element` throws an exception if `element` is not `Interval` that, of course, can be regarded as "check"

Comment: @Igor how element can not be interval if previous line says `if (element.GetType() == typeof(Interval))`. Of course `element as Interval` is more efficient, but simple cast solves OP error

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void DisplayList<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    foreach (T element in list)
    {
        var interval = element as Interval;
        if (interval != null)
            DisplayInterval(interval);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast Whatever type your element is to an Interval like this:
    public class Interval
    {
        public int start;
        public int end;
        public Interval() { start = 0; end = 0; }
        public Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; }
    }

```
public static void DisplayInterval(Interval inter)
{
    Console.Write(" [{0},{1}]",inter.start,inter.end);
}

public static void DisplayList<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    foreach (T element in list)
    {
        if (element.GetType() == typeof(Interval))
            DisplayInterval((Interval)element);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you are inheriting from Interval you may need to change you type comparison to something like

```
if (element is Interval)
```

OR

```
if(typeof(Interval).IsAssignableFrom(element.GetType()))
```